# How do I get the negation of a mongoid query?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

In my app I have the query:

`Model.where(flagged: true, saved: false)`

Alternatively I can use `Model.all(:conditions => {flagged: true, saved: false})`

That's all fine.

Now how do I get the negation of that query? i.e. all the instances of Model which do not satisfy `flagged: true` AND `saved: false` (which is the equivalent of `flagged != true` OR `saved != false`)

`Model.excludes(flagged: true, saved: false)` returns me the instances which satisfy `flagged != true` AND `saved != false`)

Comment: Hey are you still having trouble?

Comment: @tyler - Thanks for asking. No, I've worked around the issue. It wasn't blocking me, just meant my code could not be as elegant as I'd like.

Comment: Oh, well check out my answer. I think it accurately does what you are looking for, either way, cheers on getting it solved.

Comment: @tyler - thanks, but as I put in the comments to Russell's answer, I'd like to know if it is possible in the general case, not just for my specific condition. I guess mongoid could do the boolean expansion, but from the sound of it Russell would be against that

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have found I can do this using [Javascript expression syntax](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-JavascriptExpressionsand%7B%7B%24where%7D%7D)

So the negation of `Model.where(flagged: true, saved: false)` - which can be expressed as `Model.where("this.flagged == true && this.saved == false")`

is

```
Model.where("!(this.flagged == true && this.saved == false)")
```

As Russell's comment suggests this is less efficient than using the native query language, but for my purposes that is not a problem so I am marking this correct for now - but for future readers bear in mind the performance implications.

If someone can give an answer that uses only the native query language, without doing an explicit boolean logic expansion, I'll mark that correct (maybe that will be possible in a future version of Mongodb/Mongoid - if it can't be done now.)

Comment: This is really bad for performance and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: Never do it this way, Javascript expressions cannot use the index. You should only use them when the query can only be expressed with the built in operators (which it can)

Comment: 'Never'? Surely it dependes on the circumstances. In my case performance is not an issue as the data set is, and will stay, of modest size.

Answer (score 1):

You need to drop down to the MongoDB ruby driver to do this.

If I'm understanding the question correctly, Mongoid's exclude command does an AND when you are looking for an OR between the $ne clauses and there is no method for it.

This is what you would want in the shell:

```
find({$or: [{flagged: {$ne: true}}, {saved: {$ne: true}}]})
```

In ruby, that query looks like this:

```
query = {"$or" => [{"flagged" => {"$ne" => true}}, {"saved" => {"$ne" => true}}]}
```

If I recall correctly you can say:

`Model.collection.find(query)` where the query is the document i defined above, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `$nor` operator?

```
Model.all(:conditions => { '$nor' => [ { flagged: true }, { saved: false } ]})
```

More info: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nor/

Answer (score -1):

For the specific case you use in your question, you can do:

```
Model.any_of({ flagged: false, saved: true }, { flagged: true, saved: true }, { flagged: false, saved: false } )
```

However, as you say in your comments, you're actually looking for a general solution. AFAIK there is no way to do this in Mongoid or in MongoDB.

The reason for this most probably lies in the fact that you cannot do joins in a MongoDB query. For example, a traditional SQL way to get a negation of a query might be:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable t 
WHERE t.id NOT IN ( SELECT t2.id FROM mytable t2 WHERE t2.condition = true )
```

Or, to avoid the N+1 selects issue

```
SELECT t.*, t2.id FROM mytable t
OUTER JOIN mytable t2 ON ( t1.id AND t2.condition = true )
WHERE t2.id = NULL
```

Both of which rely on joining two selects in some way, which in Mongo you can't do.

The only other way is to somehow invert the logic as I do to get the above answer to your specific example. I think it would be a very bad idea to ask Mongo to do this automatically as you would end up with code generating arbitrarily complex queries which you would have no control over and would be unable to optimise.

Comment: Yes you are. That gets me all models where flagged=false AND saved=true. The negation of my query should get models where (flagged=false AND saved=true) OR (flagged=true AND saved=true) OR (flagged=false AND saved=false)

Comment: I see, my mistake. I've updated my answer with something that should *work*; if I think of anything more succinct or performant I'll update it with that.

Comment: Thanks. That should work, but I was looking for a general answer to query negation (or to be told mongoid doesn't support it). It won't expand very well if I want the negation of a query with N parameters where N is not small.

Comment: I think you'll find that Mongoid won't support it as there's no way AFAIK to do it with MongoDB other than constructing the reverse query yourself. You can't do joins in Mongo so the only *standard* way to do a negation that I can think of would be to run your query, then do a `not in` query for all the keys it returns.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but I don't see how it's anything to do with joins. It's boolean logic expansion.

Comment: The reason I mention joins is that this is how - to the best of my knowledge - a SQL database would return the negation of a query. If you are relying on a framework to do a load of boolean logic expansion / reversal then you are trusting it to create arbitrarily complex queries that you have no control over and cannot optimise yourself. Joining to the original query to exclude those values would be the only reliable, consistent way to do a negation while taking advantage of the human thought and expertise that went into constructing the original query.

Comment: No, SQL wouldn't use a join to do this. It would just be SELECT * FROM model WHERE NOT(flagged = true AND saved = false)

Comment: That's a logical inversion which a human would do - but a *generic* inversion performed by a DB would most likely involve a join. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: What are you talking about - thats a valid SQL statement.

Comment: I didn't say it was invalid. But I strongly suspect if you looked at the execution plan of a sufficiently complex query of that form you would see it was done with a subselect, then a select excluding the subselect.

Comment: In postgres (at least) it does the boolean expansion of the conditions when wrapping the entire condition in NOT(). See: https://skitch.com/dansingerman/gh6tw/not-query-postgres-localhost-5432

Comment: Which is why I said sufficiently complex. Regardless - if I need a complex query I'd rather write it myself than rely on a library to do it for me. I don't know your use case so don't understand why you really need to do this - but it feels like a code smell to me.

Comment: How complex do you want it while only selecting from a single table (so not a join by definition) - can you give any example where the DB query analyzer (not a framework) turns a negation into a join?

Comment: Then if you're only selecting from a single table and it's not that complex, write it yourself!

Comment: The point was whether the issue of Mongo not doing this was anything to do with joins. I am yet to see anything that suggests that - it seems to be that Mongodb/mongoid just hasn't implemented boolean logic expansion (yet). Thanks for your input though :-)